# How to use foreach in for loops?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Hey there I have the following code snippet:

```
$connection =  new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'XXXX', 'test') ;
$id_value = $connection->query("Select id from pbx");
for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) 
{   
    if(count($data->sheets[$i]['cells'])>0)     {
        for($j=2;$j<=count($data->sheets[$i]['cells']);$j++){ 
            for($k=1;$k<=count($data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j]);$k++)
            $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][1];
            $User = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][1]);
            $Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][2]);
            $HR_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][3]);

            foreach($id_value as $id_value){
            echo $id_value['id']."<br/>";
        }
    }   
}   
}
```

When I execute the script I get the following error messages:

> Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id_value' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\var\www\classes\test4.php on line 36
>
> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\var\www\classes\test4.php on line 35

If I use the foreach outside the first "for" loop it works. However I can not use it inside. Is it not possible to use a foreach in a for loop? Can you please help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is not possible to use a `foreach` with a variable name to assign values being the same as the array name you want to iterate. (`$id_value` here).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments. It is not possible to use a foreach with a variable name to assign values. I changed it to:

```
foreach($id_value as $id_wert){
        echo $id_wert['id']."<br/>";
    }
```

And now it works fine.